# Tell Linux scheduler not to use certain CPU cores at runtime?

Tags: linux, cpu, scheduled-tasks, linux-kernel

I want to absolutely remove certain CPU cores from Linux scheduler.

All I found on the Internet is [adding `isolcpus` to grub with rebooting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208538/telling-linux-kernel-not-to-use-certain-cpus).

But it there a way to do it at runtime (without reboot)?

Answer (score 1):

A search with `linux disable cpu core at runtime`, brings up, on the very first hit....

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
```

Although, on my system at least, you cannot do that with `cpu0`.

Comment: You cannot do that with `cpu0` on any x86-based system – something to do with certain interrupts always going to the 'boot' CPU.